# android: how to track a person's location using open street map via GPS

Tags: java, android

how to track a person's location using open street map via GPS

Comment: Belongs on stalkers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

- Tracking somebody else's location: *"Google locations".*

  Tracking your own location: Have a look at this opensource project: [open-gpstracker page](http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have everybody who wants to be involved have your app on their phone. The app will then upload their location to your server and the other people's apps will download the locations into their phones. From there you can pretty easily feed the location data into Maps. Be aware that collecting and broadcasting location data leads you into a privacy minefield of potentially epic proportions so think it all through before you cause yourself a world of trouble.

Open Street Maps will only come into it when you go to display the locations. If the user chooses to display location data in an OSM app it'll show up there.

I've been using the Manning book Android In Action (2nd edition) to learn Android, I suggest you do the same. It has good chapters on collecting location data and communicating with web services, which are the two main pieces of your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,this)
```

use this code whithin on create